# Excel Macro to create graphs for distinct values

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I am working in Excel on data sheet with ~25000 rows. Each row has a column for product code, date and weight. I would like to create a macro that generates a scatter plot of the weights for each product code (date on the x-axis, weight on the y-axis). I have the data sorted by product code and also have a 4th column that identifies when a row has a new product code from the one before.

[image]

I have recorded a macro where I create a single graph for a product code but I am unsure how to modify it so that it can go through the entire worksheet and group the rows with the same code and create a graph for each.

I have included a screenshot of my data. This is the code for the recorded macro:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
' graph
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+g
'
    Range("B12:B19,D12:D19").Select
    Range("D12").Activate
    Charts.Add2
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
        "'Cleaned Up'!$B$12:$B$19,'Cleaned Up'!$D$12:$D$19")
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
    Sheets("Cleaned Up").Select
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're looking to aggregate by code and summarize via graph makes me think you're better off using a Pivot Table.

You cant usually do a scatter as Pivot Chart. [But you can use this work-around](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-scatter-pivot-chart) to make a scatter plot work with pivot data.

So I'd format the raw data on one sheet. Create a pivot with your aggregated values / customize summary. Then use the pivot-scatter work around.

Keep the workbook as a template of sorts. So when you want to re-create the analysis, you don't need a macro. You just plug a new set of data on the data tab, refresh the pivot, and the chart will show your scatter.